# Trying to use an attribute from a JSON array (angularjs)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays, json

**UPDATE: Now i get the data thanks to everyone with your help, but when the field is null i get the error "Cannot read property 'split' of null" What can i do?

I have this JSON data array, just a sample with 2 objects.

```
    {
    "proyecto": "Probando",
    "complejidad": "Media",
    "glosa": "QA",
    "inicio": "30-06-16",
    "termino": "27-09-16",
    "completado": "50",
    "esperado": "100",
    "estado": "Atrasado",
    "responsable": "Lionel Messi",
    "alerta": "01-02-2017 : Se define paso a produccion para el 18-02;\r\n\r\nAnalista responsable: Ronaldo ronald;\r\nEstado Actual: 13\/05 DEF firmado;\r\n\r\nServico curse credito internet, modificar el curse y el que envia la solicitus mod 2 servicos;"
}, {
    "proyecto": "Migracion",
    "complejidad": "Alta",
    "glosa": "QA",
    "inicio": "18-01-16",
    "termino": "22-04-77",
    "completado": "27",
    "esperado": "86",
    "estado": "Atrasado",
    "responsable": "Christiano ronaldo",
    "alerta": "08-02-2017 : Se define salida para 21 al 23 de abril, con dependencia de salida proyecto supercluster;"
}
```

This way getting the data with GET from angularjs

```
$scope.llamada3 = function(){

    $http.get("conector.php?tipoDato=query3")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.mensajeEspera = "";
        $scope.datos3 = response.data;
```

Im trying to get the attribute "alerta" from it so i can split the field where the ";" ends but is not working. I have this at the moment

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.datos3.length; i++){
    var currentObj = $scope.datos3[i];
    currentObj.alerta[i] = $scope.datos3.currentObj[i].alerta.split(';');
}
```

And in the HTML im using ng-repeat

```
<tr ng-repeat="z in datos3">
        <td style="vertical-align: top;"><a  href="#" ng-click="mostrar_proyecto(z.project_id)">{{z.proyecto}}</a></td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">{{z.complejidad}}</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">{{z.glosa}}</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">{{z.inicio}}</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">{{z.termino}}</td>    
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">{{z.estado}}</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">{{z.responsable}}</td>    
        <td style="vertical-align: top;"> 
             <div class="hooveralerta">
                <div ng-repeat="d in alerta">
                    {{d}}
                </div>
             </div>
        </td>
```

Comment: What isn't working? Please be more specific.

Comment: i checked everything, i think my problem is  in the for condition

Comment: You can use `currentObj.alerta[i] = $scope.datos3[i].alerta.split(';');` instead of `currentObj[i]`

Comment: Yes, but what is your error? What is supposed to happen and what is happening?

Comment: it should display all the data and the column "Alerta" with line breaks after the ";", that's what the for in my function is for

Comment: If you have another question, please post a new question, don't just keep adding questions to your existing one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple things going on here. First, here is no `currentObj` in `datos3`. so this won't work:

```
currentObj.alerta[i] = $scope.datos3.currentObj[i].alerta.split(';');
```

Instead, change it to something like

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.datos3.length; i++){
    var currentObj = $scope.datos3[i];
    currentObj.alertaObject = currentObj.alerta.split(';');
}
```

And if you would like to remove the line-break within your JSON object, you can include this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < datos3.length; i++){
    var currentObj = datos3[i];
    currentObj.alertaObject = currentObj.alerta.split(';');
    for (var j in currentObj.alertaObject) {
      currentObj.alertaObject[j] = currentObj.alertaObject[j].replace(/\n/g,'').replace(/\r/g,'');
    }
    console.log(currentObj.alertaObject);
}
```

Finally, if what you have here is you actual JSON, then your JSON is invalid, and that could be causing a problem. You'll need to enclose your two separate objects into one containing object:

```
[{
    "proyecto": "Probando",
    "complejidad": "Media",
    "glosa": "QA",
    "inicio": "30-06-16",
    "termino": "27-09-16",
    "completado": "50",
    "esperado": "100",
    "estado": "Atrasado",
    "responsable": "Lionel Messi",
    "alerta": "01-02-2017 : Se define paso a produccion para el 18-02;\r\n\r\nAnalista responsable: Ronaldo ronald;\r\nEstado Actual: 13\/05 DEF firmado;\r\n\r\nServico curse credito internet, modificar el curse y el que envia la solicitus mod 2 servicos;"
}, {
    "proyecto": "Migracion",
    "complejidad": "Alta",
    "glosa": "QA",
    "inicio": "18-01-16",
    "termino": "22-04-77",
    "completado": "27",
    "esperado": "86",
    "estado": "Atrasado",
    "responsable": "Christiano ronaldo",
    "alerta": "08-02-2017 : Se define salida para 21 al 23 de abril, con dependencia de salida proyecto supercluster;"
}]
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/mspinks/yfyaehd7/

Comment: thanks for your answer, i tried chaging the loop like you said. Now it display the error "Cannot read property 'split' of null"

Comment: @frager0, also check your JSON code. If it looks exactly like that, then it's invalid json. Your two separate objects need to be enclosed within a containing object. Check my updated answer, which includes a working sample: https://jsfiddle.net/mspinks/yfyaehd7/

Comment: now i get the data with the line breaks!!, I think my error is when i get null fields it cant split them. How can i fix that?

Comment: Well, there ARE line breaks within the original JSON object. That's what `\n` and `\r` are (escaped values for "new-line" and "carriage return"). If you want to remove those, however, you can, using the javascript `replace` function. Check the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mspinks/yfyaehd7/

Comment: Also, I have updated my answer to include the possibility of removing line breaks within the strings, if that is what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing an undefined with: `$scope.datos3.currentObj[i].alerta.split(';');` and you are not storing these changes in `$scope.dataos3`

Try changing your loop to access these directly like:

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.datos3.length; i++){
    $scope.datos3[i].alerta = (typeof $scope.datos3[i].alerta == 'string') 
        ? $scope.datos3[i].alerta.split(';') 
        : [];
}
```

The above should only be performed within or after your `$http.get()` has completed.

Example:

```
$http.get("conector.php?tipoDato=query3")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.mensajeEspera = "";
        $scope.datos3 = response.data;
        // Do the alteration here
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.datos3.length; i++){
            $scope.datos3[i].alerta = (typeof $scope.datos3[i].alerta == 'string') 
                ? $scope.datos3[i].alerta.split(';') 
                : [];
        }
    };
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i tried chaging the loop like you said. Now it display the error "Cannot read property 'split' of null"

Comment: Is your JSON response valid? Because the code in your question is not valid JSON it is missing array brackets: `[ ... ]`

Comment: yes, sorry i just copied 2 objects as a sample. I get all the attributes, just the field "Alerta" is missing

Comment: You need to also make sure to do any manipulation after you get your response back from your `$http.get()`, I can update my answer.

Comment: now i get the data with the line breaks, I think my error is when i get null fields it cant split them. How can i fix that?

Comment: You would need to add condition, but it shouldn't cause a fatal error.